# Nodemailer w Google Mail Service Account error on sendmail()

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, gmail-api, nodemailer

I am trying to send email from a Firebase function,  at this point I can get the jwt client, authorize iy, get tokens and create a nodemailer transporter. 
BUT trying perorm the transporter.sendmail(), I get an error :

```
info: { Error: Invalid status code 401
        at ClientRequest.req.on.res (/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/VUE.JS-vcli-3-beta/le-choro-des-charentes/functions/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/fetch/index.js:221:23)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:551:21)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:23)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
        at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
        at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
      type: 'FETCH',
      sourceUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
      code: 'EAUTH',
      command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2' }
```

after reading a lot of posts ( Q&A in so many different contexts ) I'm lost...  My feeling is that this error could be related to the refresk token... but who knows ?

Here is my function ( I inserted some console.log to watch it progressing ..., and all env variables are set w functions.config() ) :

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();

    const { google } = require('googleapis')
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')

    exports.sendContactEmailOAuth = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      const sender_email = 'john.doe@acme.com';
      const sender_msg = 'just a test to contact the site owner.'
      const email = 'contact@example.com'

      const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
        email: functions.config().service_key.client_email,
        key: functions.config().service_key.private_key,
        scopes: ['https://mail.google.com/']
        }
      )

      console.log('JWT Client: ', jwtClient)

      jwtClient.authorize((error, tokens) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('NOT AUTHORIZE?: ', error)
          res.json({ success: false, error: error });
          return
        }
        console.log('AUTHORIZED tokens: ', tokens)

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.gmail.com",
          port: 465,
          secure: true,
          auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            user: email,
            serviceClient: functions.config().service_key.client_id,
            privateKey: functions.config().service_key.private_key,
            accessToken: tokens.access_token,
            refreshToken: tokens.refresh_token,
            expires: tokens.expiry_date
          }
        });

        console.log('nodemailer transporter set...');

        const mailOptions = {
          from: 'An Example<' + sender_email + '>',
          to: email,
          subject: 'Apple and Banana',
          text: sender_msg,
          html: '<h1>Apple and Banana</h1><p>My html here</p>'
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.end('error');
          } else {
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
            res.end('sent');
          }
          transporter.close();
        });
      });
    });
```

Now I can see the console output :

```
    =====================

    info: User function triggered, starting execution

    info: JWT Client:  JWT {
      domain: null,
      _events: {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      transporter: DefaultTransporter {},
      credentials: { refresh_token: 'jwt-placeholder', expiry_date: 1 },
      certificateCache: null,
      certificateExpiry: null,
      refreshTokenPromises: Map {},
      _clientId: undefined,
      _clientSecret: undefined,
      redirectUri: undefined,
      authBaseUrl: undefined,
      tokenUrl: undefined,
      eagerRefreshThresholdMillis: 300000,
      email: 'postman@example-209605.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
      keyFile: undefined,
      key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvAI........IZFwQg==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n',
      scopes: [ 'https://mail.google.com/' ],
      subject: undefined,
      additionalClaims: undefined }

    info: AUTHORIZED tokens:  { access_token: 'ya29.c.Elm6BYmTEQ6B82VWaAVx-9oXxX0ytUhgag-FJNPzFl1R9zEeeQQsGuMB5XnMrnbRRZBQuJkprvW1E_Sh8spyEmbd4iwAXbaj2Ou9vcww',
      token_type: 'Bearer',
      expiry_date: 1526217245000,
      id_token: undefined,
      refresh_token: 'jwt-placeholder' }

    info: nodemailer transporter set...

        info: { Error: Invalid status code 401
            at ClientRequest.req.on.res (/Users/myself/Developments/myapp/functions/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/fetch/index.js:221:23)
            at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
            at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
            at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:551:21)
            at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:23)
            at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
            at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
            at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
            at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
            at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
          type: 'FETCH',
          sourceUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
          code: 'EAUTH',
          command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2' }
```

1. Is the jwt client OK ?  I guess a sit's authorized.
2. Are the tokens OK ?  id_token: undefined and refresh_token: 'jwt-placeholder'?
3. what the meaning of this Invalid status code 401 ?

Thanks for feedback.  I am not far from getting it up and running, but it's the last issue after a long journey into GMail Service Account authentication.

Comment: I guess there is no harm in posting your bearer token once it is expired, but please check it that your other private data, like project ID don't appear in the question.

Comment: Here is a gcloud command to sign a JWT. Could you check if your script/request works when you do the signing with it? Compare JWT created by gcloud and by you in [JWT.io](https://jwt.io).